# Can you add multiple classes to an element with tal attribute?

Tags: php, html, phptal

[tal:attributes](http://phptal.org/manual/en/split/tal-attributes.html)

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
<div tal:define="two python: 'panel-heading'" tal:attributes="class group/id two" >
```

Comment: Have you tried just `<div tal:attributes="class one two three"></div>`? I don't see what you would need a comma for. However, it looks like you need to define `$one $two $three` variables to use tal.

Comment: ExpressionError: Not a valid path-expression. That is what it tells me when I have two variables there.